# Select only one row with same key value from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
reg_no    |    cname    |  no
1         |    X        |  1
1         |    Y        |  2
2         |    X        |  1
2         |    Y        |  2
```

What I want to do is to select all that rows but I only want one row for each reg_no when I arrange it in desc (it should only get the row with highest no for each reg_no).

The output should be:

```
1 Y 2
2 Y 2
```

Comment: Did you tried anything ?? Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: I'm using sql server 2000.. I tried using distinct but it doesnt gave me the result i need

Comment: If i use top, for example top 1, it only gives me one row

Answer (score 2):

Use `Row_Number()` window function

```
select Reg_no,C_name,no from
(
select row_number() over(partition by reg_no order by no desc) Rn,*
from yourtable
) A
where rn=1
```

or `ANSI SQL` standard will work in `sql server 2000`. Find the `max` no in each `reg_no` then `join` the result back to the main table.

```
select A.Reg_no,A.C_name,A.no 
from yourtable As A
Inner Join
(
select max(no) As no,Reg_no
from yourtable
group by Reg_No
) As B
on A.No=B.No and A.Reg_No=B.Reg_no
```

Answer (score 1):

In MSSQL using CROSS APPLY this would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    r1.reg_no, r2.cname, r2.no
FROM
    table_name r1 
CROSS APPLY 
(SELECT TOP 1
    r.cname, r.no
FROM 
    table_name r
WHERE r1.reg_no = r.reg_no 
ORDER BY r.no DESC) r2
```